# Multi level Drop Down with a gap

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have built a nav bar which has a dropdown and inside this dropdown when each item is hovered, another drop down appears in tree view.

I don't want it to be in tree view, I want to be at same starting height.

What I mean is when I select the second item the second dropdown at right appears with a gap above, I don't want it. Please ignore other errors.

**Here is the code:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header-bottom {
    height: 8vh;
    background-color: #283045;
    position: relative;
  }
  
.navigation-menu {
    height: 100%; /* Set the navigation menu's height to 100% of its parent (.header-bottom) */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: auto;
    padding-left: 13%;
    padding-right: 9.5%;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.navigation-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; /* Remove default margin */
    padding: 0; /* Remove default padding */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation-menu .nav-content {
    height: 100%; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navigation-menu .nav-content .nav-link{
    display: inline-block;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.navigation-menu .nav-content li a {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navigation-menu .nav-content li a .arrow-down{
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}
/*Initially setting up */

.navigation-menu .nav-menu{
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
}

.navigation-menu .dropdown-menu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #283045;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
}


.navigation-menu .dropdown-menu li {
    padding: 7px 30px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
}

.navigation-menu .dropdown-menu li .arrow-right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}  
  
.navigation-menu .dropdown-menu li a {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
  
  /* Show the dropdown when the parent li is hovered */
.navigation-menu .nav-content li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.navigation-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-sub-menu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 100%;
    background-color: #283045;
    z-index: 1;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
}


.navigation-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-sub-menu li {
    padding: 7px 30px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
}

.navigation-menu .dropdown-menu li .dropdown-sub-menu .arrow-right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}  
  
.navigation-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-sub-menu li a {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
  
  /* Show the dropdown when the parent li is hovered */
.navigation-menu .nav-content>li:hover .dropdown-menu li:hover .dropdown-sub-menu {
    display: block;
}

.navigation-menu .request-catalog-ul {
    height: 100%; /* Set the request-catalog-ul's height to 100% of its parent (.navigation-menu) */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.request-catalog a {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

.request-catalog {
    background-color: #3695a3;
    height: 8vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.request-catalog:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.request-catalog:hover a {
    color: #030d25;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.navigation-menu .nav-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #3695a3;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.navigation-menu .nav-menu .active {
    background-color: #3695a3;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.navigation-menu .nav-menu li:active {
    background-color: #3695a3;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.navigation-menu .nav-menu li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header-bottom">
            <nav class="navigation-menu" role="navigation">
              <ul class="nav-menu">
                <div class="nav-content">
                  <li class="nav-link {%if request.path == Store %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a href="{% url 'Store' %}" class="level-top" title="Shop By Category"><span>Janitorial Supplies</span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Wet Mop</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-sub-menu top">
                          <li><a href="#">Hop Heads</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Mop Heads </a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Wet Heads </a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Wet Mop</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-sub-menu top">
                          <li><a href="#">Hop Heads</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Mop Heads </a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Wet Heads </a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-link {%if request.path == Cart %}active{% endif %}">
                    <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
                    <a href="{% url 'Cart' %}" class="level-top" title="Resources"><span>Hospitality Supplies</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-link {%if request.path == Checkout %}active{% endif %}">
                    <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="level-top" title="Buy For Your Home"><span>Resources</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-link {%if request.path == Store1 %}active{% endif %}">
                    <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="level-top" title="Contact Us"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-link {%if request.path == Pdf_download %}active{% endif %}">
                    <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="level-top" title="Promotions"><span>Promotions</span></a>
                  </li>
                </div>
              </ul>
              <ul class="request-catalog-ul">
                <li>
                  <div class="request-catalog">
                    <a href="#" class="level-top" title="Request Catalog"><span>Request Catalog</span></a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="animation-hover start-home"></div>
            </nav>
          </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the gap shown in the image to be removed, there will also be many items. So for all items they should be starting at same height without any gaps. Please ignore other errors like hover errors I will fix it later

[image]